# C Printing value of specified coordinates in ncurses

Tags: c, coordinates, ncurses, curses

I created Tic Tac Toe using Ncurses. Is there any function which prints on a screen value of specified coordinates?

Example:

result of game:

XOO

OOX

XXO

Then, program asks user to write coordinates. User writes y=3 x=3, and program's respond is O. For user's respond of x=1 y=1, program's respond is X, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything from ncurses for this.  If you have the values for Players X and O, you should already know the coordinates.  I assume you have values in a 3x3 array (or some kind of equivalent, say `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`), as this is a fundamental prerequisite for the game (state has to be held somewhere).

Lets say you've got

```
int board[3][3];
```

and assume the  value for `X` is 1 (one) and `O` is 0 (zero).  If they ask for x,y coordinates `{ 3, 3 }` just give them:

std::cout << (board[coordX - 1][coordY - 1]) ? 'X' : 'O'; // I assume array is zero-based hence coord - 1

Code not tested, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

`[mvinch(3)][1]` (or friends) should do it, if you know where on the screen your board is displayed.

But as @frasnian says, it's more conventional to have an off-screen data structure with the state of the board.

Answer (score -1):

All the Xes Oes are given by player:

getyx(stdscr,y,x);
mvaddch(y,x,'X');

I don't have a board 3x3.